# Using other plugins or dependencies from custom maven plugins

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin

I have ended up in a situation where I need to create a Maven Plugin which as part of it's job needs to inspect a number of dependencies and find certain xml files.

(If anyone has a better way of reading files inside an artifact jar, please say so as that will very much also be considered an accepted answer)

I need to inspect a number of known dependencies that I have referenced as `org.apache.maven.artifact.Artifact` references and find all XML files within them. The only way I know of is to unpack the artifact and search though the file system. I basically need to do exactly what the Maven Dependency Plugin's "unpack" goal does. So how do I use the Maven Dependency Plugin from my own plugin? Do I simply use it as a normal Dependency or is there a more "maven" way of doing it?

EDIT:

I encountered another thing which is close enough to this one that I will update the question instead of posting a new one.
If I need to use an outside dependency, such as Jackson for example, how do I include the dependency for the plugin? It feels wrong to create a fat jar with the dependencies in it. Is there another trick I am missing?

Comment: Having an jar file on the classpath? If so read them via `class.getResoucesAsStream(..)`?

Comment: I don't know what the file is called, so I have to scan for the file first, before I can read it as a stream.